# Forbidden zone in the VTC of a buffer

Tags: digital-logic, noise

I've been following the MITOCW course by Chris Terman called "[Computer Structure](https://t.co/m3XcpjeGeY)". There he mentions the solution to the noise problem while determining appropriate voltage levels for representing binary input and output bits.

[image: slide from the lesson: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/6-004-computation-structures-spring-2017/pages/c2/c2s2/c2s2v6/]

### First Question

Here, I am assuming the reason why \$V_{IL} > V_{OL}\$ is for providing more 'padding' for the input signal. The same logic applies to why  \$V_{IH} > V_{LH}\$. Please correct me if I'm wrong about this.

In the next slide, he provides the VTC of a buffer:
[image: slide from the same class mentioned in previous slide]

### Second Question

In this VTC, I do not understand the values that lie between  \$V_{IL}\$ and \$ V_{IH}\$. Those values are neither less than \$V_{IL}\$ nor greater than \$V_{IH}\$. Shouldn't they lie in the forbidden zone?

[image: my annoatation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The noise margin allows the output signal to be shifted by noise and still be recognized as valid by the next input.

In the first image, the forbidden zone applies to the input, i.e., it describes which input voltages your circuit is not allowed to apply to the input.

In the second image, the forbidden zone describes the relationship between the input and the output, i.e., the output is guaranteed to be not in its forbidden zone as long as the input is not in its forbidden zone. Or, when the input is valid, the output is guaranteed to be valid.

The VTC curve shows the input and output voltages in the forbidden zones because, when you are switching between low and high, they must go through this zone. But the exact behaviour in this zone is not guaranteed. And with digital signal, you never stay long in the forbidden zone.